# What purpose does the list of tables and figures serve, and how can I make them more useful?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

Large documents (a thesis for example) have lists of tables and figures after the table of contents.

What purpose does this list serve to the reader? Most technical books I have don't include them, and I feel like most people skip right over them.

Is there a reason to include these lists? How can I make the lists more useful to a reader of my thesis?

Comment: There's no particular reason for adding those lists. In some cases, figures or tables are very important and having their captions and locations in a single place can be useful for browsing the document. If you don't feel the necessity, just don't make the lists.

Comment: Can you make this into a question specific to using TeX and friends? Is there a specific improvement to the lists you'd like help with?

Comment: @AndrewCashner, I was debating between posting this question here or over at Academia.SX. Thoughts?

Comment: Go back writing your thesis instead of asking questions on tex.SX!

Comment: @Felix If you can make the question center on how to use TeX, including some sample code, then post it here. Otherwise it's off topic. (FWIW I find these lists useful in large technical theses, and they are no trouble to prepare in LaTeX. They are also easy to remove if you change your mind.)

Comment: This is an excellent question for typesetting but not as good as asking here. We rarely manage to get to a conclusion about the usage of anything. For example, the `booktab` people promote avoiding vertical lines in tables others say such prohibition is pointless etc. so this is for my understanding either goes to UX.stackexchange.com or academia or last resort graphic design.SE